Why isn't my mnist model reading my handwritten number correctly?
I used a sequential neural network and created a simple paint app in pygame to draw an integer. It then goes to attempt a read off of that image.
This first part is my neural network file.
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import paint

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

#x_train = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_train, axis = 1)
#x_test = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_test, axis = 1)

x_train = x_train.reshape((60000, 28, 28, 1)) / 255.0
x_test = x_test.reshape((10000, 28, 28, 1)) / 255.0


model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape = (28,28))) # input layer, flattened image
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation = "relu")) # hidden
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = "relu")) # hidden
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation = "softmax")) # output
model.compile(optimizer = "adam", loss = "sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics = ["accuracy"])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 5)

model.save("Aahans.network")

paint.paintcall()

image = cv2.imread("/Users/aahan_bagga/Documents/DataScience/digit.png")[:,:,0]
image = np.invert(np.array([image])) #black on white

model.predict(image)

print(f"This digit is probably {np.argmax(model.predict(image))}")

#if image is not None:
    #print("Image loaded successfully.")
    #print("Image shape:", image.shape)

    #white_background = np.ones_like(image) * 255

    # Overlay the image on the white canvas
    #result = cv2.addWeighted(white_background, 1, image, 0.5, 0)

    # Display the resulting image
    #cv2.imshow("Image with White Background", result)
    #cv2.imshow("image", image)
    #cv2.waitKey(0)
    #cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    #print(f"This digit is probably {np.argmax(model.predict(image))}")
#else:
    #print("Error: Image not loaded.")

This second part is my paint app.
import pygame
import cv2
import numpy as np

def paintcall(): 

# Initialize Pygame
pygame.init()

# Constants
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 512, 512 # Updated size to 28 by 28 pixels
BG_COLOR = (255, 255, 255)
DRAW_COLOR = (0, 0, 0)
DRAW_SIZE = 30  # Adjusted size for better visibility on a small screen

# Create the screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.flip()
pygame.display.set_caption("Paint App")

# Create a surface to draw on
drawing_surface = pygame.Surface((WIDTH, HEIGHT), pygame.SRCALPHA)

# Main loop
drawing = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
a = True
while a:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            small_img = (cv2.cvtColor(cv2.resize(np.flipud(np.rot90(pygame.surfarray.array3d(screen))), (28, 28)), cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY) / 255.0)
            small_img = small_img.reshape(28, 28, 1)
            small_img_uint8 = (small_img * 255).astype(np.uint8)
            # Save the image using OpenCV
            cv2.imwrite("digit.png", small_img_uint8)
            #pygame.image.save(drawing_surface, "digit.png")
            print("Done")
            a = False
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            drawing = True
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            drawing = False
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION and drawing:
            pygame.draw.circle(drawing_surface, DRAW_COLOR, pygame.mouse.get_pos(), DRAW_SIZE)

    # Update the display
    screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
    screen.blit(drawing_surface, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Cap the frame rate
    clock.tick(60)

#print("Finished Drawing")

It isn't able to read the drawn image correctly, and I thought it was because of the format. I enlarged the image and then condensed it to fit in the model as it takes a 28 by 28 pixel format.
What exactly is wrong here?

Have you looked at the 28x28 image with your eyes to make sure it is as distinct as you expect it to be?

yes it looks completely identical to me in the 28x28 scale.
